# Does 意思意思 have an English translation？

Tags: translation, culture

In this context，someone wants a promotion and someone needs to 意思意思 his superior；意思意思 means bribery and it is supposed to invoke nepotism。

Does English have a word or idiom like 意思意思？

Comment: answer in online dictionaries: bkrs:coll. as a mere token
以送礼、请客等方式表示心意。jukuu: 意思意思, samples 7  .  To serve as a token
 意思意思 9.  It's the thought that counts.
 意思意思就行了。

Comment: 这是我的**一点心意** / **一点表示**, means **a little something**, **compliments**, later the expression changes to 一点意思, like: 这是我的**一点意思**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'In this context，someone wants a promotion and someone needs to 意思意思 his superior；'

fawn(v.):

Old English fægnian "rejoice, be glad, exult, applaud," from fægen "glad" (see fain); used in Middle English to refer to expressions of delight, especially a dog wagging its tail (early 13c.), hence "court favor, grovel, act slavishly" (early 14c.). Related: Fawned; fawning.

你要讨好老板， 就是你得‘fawn'. 'fawn upon someone'

'grovelling' also has this meaning and 'curry favour with someone'.

fawn: 
to seek notice or favor by servile demeanor:

> The courtiers fawned over the king.

I found this: https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1446521891194685020.html

Comment: Suck up and brown nose maybe? I've had a very hard time to deal with huge synonyms and so-called thesaurus in English. Sometimes, I can't differentiate those.

Comment: Post the Chinese sentence you want to translate, I'll try to change it to reasonable English.

Answer (score 1):

- 意思意思*

**ABC**

> as a mere token

**KEY**

> do sth as a token; serve as a token